# Calling bat file from context menu

Tags: batch-file, registry

I made a simple batch file to create a folder.
I am trying to make that bat file I created, to execute the command and create a folder from wherever I call it from using the context menu.

My Batch File:

```
@echo off
set currentDirectory=%CD%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if not exist "%CD%\GAME\" mkdir "%CD%\GAME"
```

Here is my Reg file:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\Folders Creator]
"Position"="Top"
"SubCommands"=""
"MUIVerb"="Create Folder(s)"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\Folders Creator\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\Folders Creator\Shell\01menu]
"MUIVerb"="Create All Folders"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\Folders Creator\Shell\01menu\command]
@="\"C:\\Folders Creator\\1A.bat\""
```

The bat file I will be calling is stored in C:\Folders Creator
and thats where the folder is created and not where I call it from.

Example: I click "Create Folder" in context menu from Desktop and this where I need the folder to be created at. Not in C:\Folders Creator.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank You!!!

Comment: Your batch file could contain only a single line `MkDir` command, none of the rest is required. And you should not use a .reg file, you can use reg.exe instead. Also you are making modifications to the wrong registry root key, and your command value data string should include an argument holding the chosen directory path.

Comment: So I cut my bat file down to the one MkDir line like you mentioned and it worked.  Thank You Much @Compo

Comment: No, thats regedit.exe. Please open a Command Promp window, type `reg /?` and press the `[ENTER]` key to find out how it works. It basically means you can add your registry subkeys, values and data directly from a batch file.

Comment: Oh Wow!  Never heard of this before.  I'm going to have some studying to do.  ThanX @Compo

Comment: Caution: `%CD%` might not point to the location you intend to! It is the current directory, which depends on how you run the batch file (via Command Prompt or by double-clicking its icon), and which is not the same as the parent directory of the batch script (which would be `%~dp0.`)…